# ReactJS / MongoDB: export const Database (how to insert.before)?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I am using MeteorJS as my framework.

In my `imports/api/collections/categories.js` file, I have:

```
export const Photos = new Mongo.Collection('photos');
```

On the server side, I have:

`Photos = new Mongo.Collection('photos');`

How can I `insert.before` so all my documents have an extra field when they get added to the database?

Before I was exporting for React, I had:

```
Photos = new Mongo.Collection('photos');
Photos.before.insert(function(userId,doc){
doc.createdAt=Date.now();doc.status=0;
});
```

But that doesn't work with:

```
export const Photos...
```

Ideas how I achieve the insert before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as it turns out, I can do what I did before:

```
Photos.before.insert(function(userId,doc){doc.status=0;});
```

I just had to bring in this package into Meteor:

```
matb33:collection-hooks
```